# Increasing rounds in DES, increases or decreases the security?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, symmetric, des

I was wondering whether in `DES`,
if we used more than 16 rounds, the security of the message was increased or actually decreased?
*(disregarding the decreased speed of execution / computation.)*
Thanks in advance!

Comment: forget about my comment, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, it increases the security.

The fundamental problem with regular DES is the number of bytes used for the key. It is too low to be considered secure* (with the level of computational power it currently exist, it is feasible to brute force through DES encryption).

Try checking out 3DES article on wikipedia for more info on a better implementation of DES:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES